# Python- Formulation TI implementation in Gurobi using Python. Keyerror

Tags: python, gurobi

[I want to implement the following integer programming formulations for the machine scheduling problem but keeps getting the keyerror(0,9) in line 22](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnqJw.jpg)

```
procTime = [40,28,18,38]
dueDate = [38,23,17,25]
nJobs = len(procTime)
T = sum(procTime)

x = {}
for j in range(nJobs):
    for t in range(nJobs):
        x[j,t] = m.addVar(obj=1,vtype=GRB.BINARY,name='x%d%d' % (j,t))

c = {}
for j in range(nJobs):
    c[j,t] = m.addVar(obj=1,vtype=GRB.INTEGER,name='c%d%d' % (j,t)) 

m.update()  

for j in range(nJobs):
    m.addConstr(quicksum([x[j,t] for t in range(T-procTime[j]+1)]) == 1, 'seq%d' % (j))

for t in range(T+1):
    m.addConstr(quicksum([quicksum([x[j,s] for j in range(nJobs) for s in range(max(t-procTime[j]+1),min(T-procTime[j]+2))])]) <= 1, 'time%d' % t)

for j in range(nJobs):
    for t in range(T+1):
        m.addConstr(t+procTime[j]-1-dueDate[j] <= c[j,t], 'c%d' % (j,t))

m.optimize()
```

Comment: There are multiple mistakes in this code. It will be much easier to get right if you rewrite it using the syntax `Model.addVars()` and `Model.addConstrs()` from version 7.0.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with the range on quicksum([x[j,t] for t in range(T-procTime[j]+1)]). because for x[j,t], j is in [0,3], t also in [0,3] or T =124 then T-procTime[j]+1 is in [124-0+1,124-3+1].